# Splitting Column Header Into Row Elements In R

Tags: r, algorithm, package

After performing data analysis on a larger data set using R, I get output as shown in following sample data:

```
   A_B C_D E_F G_H
1   1   1   0   0 
2   1   0   1   1
3   1   1   0   1
4   0   0   1   1
5   1   0   1   1
6   0   0   0   1
```

Currently, I am trying to split the column header into such that they appear in two different column as element, and I get the sum of the column they represented. It will look something like this:

```
   P1  P2  Sum
1   A   B   4
2   C   D   2
3   E   F   3
4   G   H   5
```

For sum of each column, I can directly make use of `colSums()`, however I am getting tangled on how splitting the column header and making them appear as cell element described above.

Please let me know any suggestions on how I can approach this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Generate Sample Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A_B = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), C_D = c(1L, 0L, 
 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), E_F = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), G_H = c(0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("A_B", "C_D", "E_F", "G_H"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
 "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

#### Method 1: `strsplit`

```
d1 <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(df1), "_")), Sum = as.vector(colSums(df1)))
names(d1)[1:2] <- c('P1', 'P2')
d1
#   P1 P2 Sum
#1  A  B   4
#2  C  D   2
#3  E  F   3
#4  G  H   5
```

---

#### Method 2:  `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1) %>%
       separate(key, into = c('P1', 'P2')) %>% 
       group_by(P1, P2) %>% 
       summarise(Sum = sum(value))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   P1 [?]
#     P1    P2   Sum
#  <chr> <chr> <int>
#1     A     B     4
#2     C     D     2
#3     E     F     3
#4     G     H     5
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. Are you sure about `names(df1)`? I get following error while trying your method `Error in strsplit(names(d1), "_") : non-character argument`. What G. Grothendieck above suggested is working, but want to try your method too.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil  Do you have a `matrix` or `data.frame`?  If it is `matrix` then do `strsplit(colnames(df1), "_")`

Comment: Yes @akrun, it's `matrix`. And it works accurately now. Your method also gives data output in form as I asked in first comment to G. Grothendieck's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try `read.table(text = ...)` like this.  Omit `as.is = TRUE` if you prefer factor columns.

In the Note below we have assumed a data frame but if the input were a matrix then the same code should work.

No packages are used.

```
DF2 <- read.table(text = colnames(DF), sep = "_", as.is = TRUE, col.names = c("P1", "P2"))
data.frame(DF2, Sum = colSums(DF), row.names = NULL)
```

giving:

```
  P1 P2 Sum
1  A  B   4
2  C  D   2
3  E  F   3
4  G  H   5
```

**Note:** The input data frame used above in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "A_B C_D E_F G_H
1   1   1   0   0 
2   1   0   1   1
3   1   1   0   1
4   0   0   1   1
5   1   0   1   1
6   0   0   0   1"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks @GGrothendieck, your suggestion works. Is it possible to remove `A_B C_D E_F G_H` row identifiers with numeric numbers, or it's not possible because of how R treats table data?

Comment: Have modified last line of code to remove X_Y row names.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1=data.frame(melt(df))%>%group_by(variable)%>%dplyr::summarise(value=sum(value))
df2 <- separate(df1, variable, into = c("P1","P2"), sep = "_", extra = "merge")

     P1    P2 value
* <chr> <chr> <int>
1     A     B     4
2     C     D     2
3     E     F     3
4     G     H     5
```